# Upload a file in my spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm trying to upload a file in my form.W hen I select a file to be uploaded all the content of the folder selected was uploaded including the target file.
I want just one file will be uploaded not all. This is the code of the upload function.

```
@PostMapping("/saveordre")
public String formOrdre(Model model ,OrdreAjout ordre1,OrdreSupp ordre2, String typeOrdre,@RequestParam("Fichier1") MultipartFile[] files, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    for(MultipartFile uploadedFile : files) {

        File file = new File(UPLOADED_FOLDER + uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            uploadedFile.transferTo(file);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        if(typeOrdre.equals("OA"))
            ordreMetier.save(ordre1);
        else
            ordreMetier.save(ordre2);   
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        model.addAttribute("error", e);
    }

    model.addAttribute("ordre", new Ordre());
    files=null;

    return "FormOrdre";
}
```

The thymeleaf template includes a from where enctype="multipart/form-data".
Anyone could help me and thanks.

Comment: I can't see the upload code : check this link it could help you :https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/

Comment: this is the upload code :  for(MultipartFile uploadedFile : files) {

        File file = new File(UPLOADED_FOLDER + uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            uploadedFile.transferTo(file);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: any news !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping("/saveordre")
public String formOrdre(Model model ,OrdreAjout ordre1,OrdreSupp ordre2, String typeOrdre,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)  {

    rootLocation=rootLocation.getRoot();
    System.out.println(rootLocation);
    String filename = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
    try {
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to store empty file " + filename);
        }
        if (filename.contains("..")) {
            // This is a security check
            throw new IOException(
                    "Cannot store file with relative path outside current directory "
                            + filename);
        }
        try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {
            Files.copy(inputStream, this.rootLocation.resolve(filename),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

    }





    try {
        if(typeOrdre.equals("OA"))
            ordreMetier.save(ordre1);
        else
            ordreMetier.save(ordre2);   

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        model.addAttribute("error", e);
    }


    model.addAttribute("ordre", new Ordre());


    return "FormOrdre";


}
```

i tried this code but an error had occurred showing that "Required request part 'file' is not present
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present".But in my form that part exists i don't know why it is not seeing by spring???